# Namespace error with ROS and OpenCV4's DNN module

Tags: c++, opencv, ros, clion

I am encountering a namespace issue when using ROS, OpenCV's dnn module, and CLion. The issue seems to be exclusive to the DNN module, as the other ROS and OpenCV functions work fine. While my code seems to compile and build fine, I am getting the lint error: `No member named readNetFromDarknet in namespace 'cv::dnn'`. The error happens everywhere I am accessing anything in the DNN module.

**Defined in my header file:**

```cpp
cv::dnn::Net net;
```

yields the error `No type named Net in namespace 'cv::dnn'`.

**Defined in my class file:**

```cpp
void HumanDetector::setupNetwork() {
    net = cv::dnn::readNetFromDarknet(MODEL_CONFIG, MODEL_WEIGHTS);
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV);
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CPU);
}
```

yields a similar problem.

In CLion, however, I can Ctrl+Click any of the alleged undefined members or types and see the source code for them. I suspect that it might have something to do with my CMakeLists config or IDE setup. Here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(followbot)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
set(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING OFF)
set(OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIR /usr/local/lib)
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/lib")

## Find catkin macros and libraries
find_package(OpenCV 4.1.2 REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        roscpp
        geometry_msgs
        std_msgs
        message_generation
        teb_local_planner
)


add_message_files(
        FILES
        Point2.msg
)

generate_messages(
        DEPENDENCIES
)


###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
        INCLUDE_DIRS include
        CATKIN_DEPENDS
            roscpp
            message_generation
            message_runtime
            std_msgs
            geometry_msgs
            teb_local_planner
        DEPENDS OpenCV
)


###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
        include
        ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/node.cpp src/cloud.cpp src/human.cpp)

## Link the executable to the OpenCV libraries
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(followbot ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: The program should be missing a path directory, be sure about the paths. I also used darknet before and got a similar error. Also try simple examples to check modules and libraries to be sure they are working well.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk i can't seem to find any incorrect configs